# Pure CSS image swap

Tags: css, image, hover

I have two images which both need to be in the HTML (so no background image), and on hover of one, it swaps for the other.

I thought I had the code working but it seems to be glitchy. I can't work out the issue.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5tCju/

Here is my CSS:

```css
#wrapper img.on,
#wrapper.gridWrap img.on {
display:none;
}

#wrapper img.default:hover img.on,
#wrapper img.default:hover img.on {
display:inline;
}

#wrapperimg.default:hover,
#wrapper img.default:hover {
display:none;
}
```

Any way this can be done by swapping the images between `display:block;` and `display:inline;` ?

Comment: Any reason for not using `MM_swapImage`? As this will generate what you want on hover. Or you can do the same by using image sprite and change background positioning?

Comment: Needs to be pure CSS. A sprite could work! Thanks

Comment: @NathanLee 1) This is a CSS question 2) Perhaps she doesn't want to buy Dreamweaver.

Comment: I don't think a sprite will work as you say they must not be a background image

Comment: Would it be possible to use `content:` css rule on hover? I haven't used it before so we are not so familiar :)

Comment: #@Francesca Are they supposed to hover each other?

Comment: They can hover over each other (they're the same image, not the ones in my example, with different colours). It needs to be pure CSS and both images need to be in the HTML.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5tCju/1/

Comment: That works, thanks! You should add it as an answer

Answer (score 5):

To get this to work, you need to set the `:hover` pseudo-class to the parent container (`.wrapper`) instead of the images.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5tCju/1/)

```
#wrapper
{
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper:hover img.default,
#wrapper img.on 
{
    display:none;
}

#wrapper:hover img.on,
#wrapper img.default 
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Pure CSS Solution.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pnerQ/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="images">&nbsp;</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.images{background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojoy/maneki-neko/256/cat-2-icon.png) no-repeat 0 0; height:300px; width:300px;}

.images:hover{background: url(https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2940708431/842924fb3e2cc1f7fddf1b195c3f6c81.jpeg) no-repeat 0 0; height:300px; width:300px; cursor:pointer;}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Cannot be background image as said in the original post

Comment: But you wanted a pure CSS Solution, so background image URL makes it pure and not affecting HTML. - @Francesca

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS Solution:

```
#wrapper img { position: absolute; float: left; }
#wrapper .on { display: none; }
#wrapper:hover .on { display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tCju/3/

Reversed version:

```
#wrapper img { position: absolute; float: left; }
#wrapper:hover .on { display: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tCju/4/

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the `display` property forces the browser to re-create the page flow, thus the flickering. A usual solution is to avoid the `<img>` tag and play with `background-image` but, if you want to use your current markup, you can simply place one image above the other:

```css
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

... and the hide/display the second one:

```css
#wrapper img.on{
    opacity: 0;
}
#wrapper img.on:hover{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

[(Updated fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5tCju/6/)

`display` would probably work better but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper img.on{
 display:none;
}
#wrapper:hover img.default{
 display:none;
}
#wrapper:hover img.on{
  display:block;
}
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5tCju/8/)**

your mistake was your were not using `:hover` properly. `.on` is not a child of `.default` thats why the statement `#wrapper img.default:hover img.on` was not working..as `.on` and `.default` both are child of  `#wrapper` thats why you should use `:hover` for your wrapper in order to change images